# wpf position sibling control with margins only

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I lay out a set of controls in xaml, I set the position using the `Canvas.Top` property.

```
<Canvas Style="{StaticResource NavMenuStyle}" Height="400" Width="100">
    <Button Canvas.Top="0" Content="A" />
    <Button Canvas.Top="80" Content="B" />
    <Button Canvas.Top="160" Content="C" />
    <Button Canvas.Top="240" Content="D" />
</Canvas>
```

I *want* to use the `Margin` property of the `<Button>` controls to position controls (like in CSS/HTML) without the controls overlapping. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StackPanel` instead of `Canvas`.